# php code error in the title

Tags: php, unix, coding-style

I have a small php coding query.

I have a index.php page referring to another page called template.php in that it contains following line:

```
?php=$this->title?
```

I guess something is not correct with this line as my Webpage, instead of loading the Name of the page, shows the above code itself.

This works on older Server. But post migration to newer server having php version 5.2 , some weird errors have popped up.

I am new to PHP so please ask if you require more Information.

Investigating further I noticed following,

at the beginning of the code there is reference to ,

[code]
" lang="">
[/code]

In working page it shows the corresponding source code as,

[code] [/code]

And problem page , it shows,

[code]" lang="">[/code]

I think this is the core problem as the lang variable is not getting loaded somehow and thats why further references to translate also fails.
My thought.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to display data in PHP with this syntax is the following :

```
<?=$this->title?>
```

Comment: Can you try var_dump($this->title); Please ?

Comment: When I see the page source the problem areas are mostly displayed as "?php=translate"   which failed to get value. So I suppose this is where the problem lies. If I can somehow resolve this problem then the page will be correcly loaded. I feel so.

Comment: The begin of PHP tags must be <?php with the <. It's important. Can you type more of your code please ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would try it and post.

I have compared the source code for the working webpage and problematic webpage.

On working webpage the source code is

[QUOTE]<h5 align="center">Please Log In</h5>[/QUOTE]

On NON working webpage the source code is

[QUOTE]<h5 align="center"><?php=translate('Please Log In')?></h5>[/QUOTE]


Does that give you any hint?

Comment: I dont know how to upload the code here. So I try to copy here,

Comment: It seems to work in a way. So When I replace the original code i.e.

Code:
<?=$this->title?>
with new code,

Code:
<?php printf ($this->title) ?>
It does give me the desired title on the title section of the webpage.

So should I change all the places where this <? paramater is? or is there something I am still missing?